# List Datasheet view stuck

Tags: list, list-view, datasheet

I have one list where it opens like normal in the Standard View format and as expected I can switch to Datasheet View. The problem occurs when I want to switch back to Standard View.

When in Datasheet View the Standard View option remains highlighted. I can only click Datasheet View, which just refreshes the list. If I want to go back to Standard View I must click the list name from the quicklaunch links. This is only happening on one list. What could be causing this issue?

note - I've tried clearing the list, thinking some of the data could be at fault but still wind up with same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. The problem occurred because a user was in edit mode. This must have caused the issue because after I had him save his changes the list acted normal again.