# Can not toggle back to Standard view of List

Tags: list, view, datasheet

I am facing a very unique problem, for which i am not even able to understand, what to look for the internet.
To give a brief :
I created a list from some List Template with content. Than added a few new columns and hide a some of the columns from from content type.

Every thing is working fine except just one thing. 
1.) When user click Datasheet view, the list open in datasheet view
2.) But in the ribbon the Standard view is still highlighted
3.) When we click back on Standard view nothing happens.

I have already gone through [List Datasheet view stuck](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87846/list-datasheet-view-stuck)

Have someone faced any such problem.
Any suggestion which could lead to the solution is totally acceptable.

**Edit**
Standard view URL : http://test.com/site/Lists/List New/AllItems.aspx

Data Sheet View URL :  http://test.com/site/Lists/List New/AllItems.aspx?ShowInGrid=True&View=%7B9E718C6B%2D0311%2D42B3%2DAE8A%2D1F2461EB0BCA%7D&InitialTabId=Ribbon%2EList&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence

Regards,
Mohit Leekha

Comment: Which browser are you using? Which version? Also, try manipulating the querystring values in your URL (compare URLs on a working list in both standard & datasheet view).

Comment: I am using IE. I have tried this in different versions of IE.
I am updating the URLS in the question. Also I just noticed in the status bar, it is saying Read Only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to solve this using the answers shared but no luck.
I just created a new list using the same template and it is working fine.
Though i am not able to find the reason but it workeded.

Answer (score 0):

Review these possible causes of the Datasheet view being read only:

- Certain columns, such as Created By and Modified, are always read-only. Values for these columns are entered automatically.
- The changes you made to the selected row or column have been submitted to the server. If there is no conflict or error, you will be able to edit the row or column after the changes have been saved.
- There is an unresolved conflict or error in the selected row or column. Resolve the conflict or error before attempting to edit the selected row or column.
- The list is set up to require content approval, and you are viewing the list in the All Items view.
- In the My Submissions view of a list that requires content approval, the Approval Status and Comment column are read-only. Only a user with Manage Lists right can edit these two columns.
- Attachments are read-only in a list that requires content approval. You cannot view or edit attachments in any of the views.
- The document in the current row has been checked out by a user. You cannot edit the columns in the row until the user checks the document in.
- You do not have permission to edit the column or row. Contact the list author for more information.

From [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/a0c52d8c-d82b-4c11-a77b-dfe10d203629/datasheet-view-is-always-readonly?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy).